# Is there a mathematical function which flips 1 and 2?

Tags: functions, arithmetic, arithmetic-functions

I'm looking for a function $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(f(x)) = x$ and $f(1) = 2$. In particular, I don't want this function to be a piecewise function. Does such a function even exist?

---

For example, I can define the above function as follows:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
2 & x = 1 \\
1 & x = 2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

However, I was wondering whether there's a way to define this function without writing conditions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a piecewise function"?

Comment: $3-x{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Wow, that was simple. Why didn't that occur to me?

Comment: @GerryMyerson how about putting that into answer? :)

Comment: @Sil, as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3-x$ (plus enough characters to qualify as an answer).

Answer (score 2):

How about $f(x) = x-(-1)^x$? That works.

Comment: O.P. also wants f(f(x))=x though.

Comment: @SquirtleSquad Sorry, I made a typo. This should work.